# Display image of graph in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, image, graph, structure, tensorflow

I wrote a simple script to calculate the golden ratio from 1,2,5.  Is there a way to actually produce a visual through tensorflow (possibly with the aid of `matplotlib` or `networkx`) of the actual graph structure? The doc of tensorflow is pretty similar to a factor graph so I was wondering:

**How can an image of the graph structure be generated through tensorflow?**

In this example below, it would be `C_1, C_2, C_3` as individual nodes, and then `C_1` would have the `tf.sqrt` operation followed by the operation that brings them together. Maybe the graph structure (nodes,edges) can be imported into `networkx`? I see that the `tensor` objects have a `graph` attribute but I haven't found out how to actually use this for imaging purposes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf
C_1 = tf.constant(5.0)
C_2 = tf.constant(1.0)
C_3 = tf.constant(2.0)

golden_ratio = (tf.sqrt(C_1) + C_2)/C_3

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(golden_ratio) #1.61803
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get an image of the graph using [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard).  You need to edit your code to output the graph, and then you can launch tensorboard and see it.  See, in particular, [TensorBoard: Graph Visualization](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz).  You create a `SummaryWriter` and include the `sess.graph_def` in it.  The graph def will be output to the log directory.

Answer (score 55):

This is exactly what tensorboard was created for. You need to slightly modify your code to store the information about your graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf
C_1 = tf.constant(5.0)
C_2 = tf.constant(1.0)
C_3 = tf.constant(2.0)

golden_ratio = (tf.sqrt(C_1) + C_2)/C_3

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    print sess.run(golden_ratio)
    writer.close()
```

This will create a `logs` folder with event files in your working directory. After this you should run tensorboard from your command line `tensorboard --logdir="logs"` and navigate to the url it gives you (http://127.0.0.1:6006). In your browser go to GRAPHS tab and enjoy your graph.

You will use TB a lot if you are going to do anything with TF. So it makes sense to learn about it more from [official](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz) and from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4).