# How to save/export a TensorFlow model (loaded from .ckpt and .meta) to a Keras model (to a .h5 file)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am loading a **MetaGraph** from .meta and .ckpt file

```
meta_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    meta_graph.restore(tf.get_default_session(), ckpt_file)
```

and a **Graph** from .pb file

```
with gfile.FastGFile(pb_file,'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

current_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

and then I would like to convert any of them into a Keras model or .h5 file directly.

But I am unable to find a helper function for this. **Neither does MetaGraph or Graph have an export utility for Keras or .h5, nor does Keras have an import function for MetaGraph or Graph.**

Please help me cross the bridge.

Files can be found here : 
https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet#pre-trained-models (VGGFace 2) or
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EXPBSXwTaqrSC0OhUdXNmKSh9qJUQ55-/view

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466066/how-can-i-convert-a-trained-tensorflow-model-to-keras

Comment: Thanks for your response but my situation is a bit different. I don't have the code for the model.