# model.summay() isn't working in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have run:

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/Urdu-Ocr/model_pb/')
```

and then want to see model summary by using:

```
print(loaded_model.summary())
```

but it gives:

```
AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Working with tensorflow 1.15.2 on google colab.

Comment: `tf.keras.models.load_model` only works with SavedModels saved from Keras. Suspecting saved model is saved with other api i.e., other than keras. Make sure use `tf.keras` api to save and load the model

Answer (score 0):

As seen from this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46210187/14290681), your Model might be a **`Frozen Model`** or a **`Check Point File`**.

Please refer the below comment which is taken from this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46210187/14290681):

> You will have to rewrite that model's code in Keras. Then, you will
> have to read the values of your variables from the checkpoint file and
> assign it to Keras model using layer.load_weights(weights) method.
>
> More than this methodology, I would suggest to you to do the training
> directly in Keras as it claimed that Keras' optimizers are 5-10% times
> faster than Tensorflow's optimizers. Other way is to write your code
> in Tensorflow with tf.contrib.keras module and save the file directly
> in hdf5 format.