# Show model layout / design (with all connections) in Keras

Tags: keras, visualization, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, machine-learning-model

I have major differences when testing a Keras LSTM model after I've trained it compared to when I load that trained model from a `.h5` file (Accuracy of the first is always > 0.85 but of the later is always below < 0.2 i.e. a random guess).

However I checked the weights, they are identical and also the sparse layout Keras give me via `plot_model` is the same, but since this only retrieves a rough overview:

**Is there away to show the full layout of a Keras model (especially node connections)?**

Answer (score 5):

If you're using tensorflow backend, apart from [`plot_model`](https://keras.io/visualization/), you can also use [`keras.callbacks.TensorBoard`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) callback to visualize the whole graph in tensorboard. Example:

```py
callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./graph', 
                                       histogram_freq=0, 
                                       write_graph=True, 
                                       write_images=True)
model.fit(..., callbacks=[callback])
```

Then run `tensorboard --logdir ./graph` from the same directory.

This is a quick shortcut, but you can go even further with that.
For example, add tensorflow code to define (load) the model within custom `tf.Graph` instance, like this:

```py
from keras.layers import LSTM
import tensorflow as tf

my_graph = tf.Graph()
with my_graph.as_default():
  # All ops / variables in the LSTM layer are created as part of our graph
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 20, 64))
  y = LSTM(32)(x)
```

.. after which you can [list all graph nodes with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35336648/712995), [evaluate any variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33679382/712995), [display the graph topology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34230613/712995) and so on, to compare the models.

I personally think, **the simplest way is to setup your own session**. It works in all cases with minimal patching:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
...
# Now can evaluate / access any node in this session, e.g. `sess.graph`
```